# Where to put my custom system-specific exceptions in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, exception

I need to create some base exception classes and inherit from it.

I see two approaches:

```
1. Create folder 'Exceptions' in library and use standard autoload mechanism
    /library
      /Exception/
        Base.php
        InvalidParameter.php
2. Just declare exception classes in model, that uses it.
```

Is there a better more "Zend-ish" approach?

Comment: I'd say option 1 is quite Zend-ish already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look into zend library, what they normally do is

```
/library
   Exception.php
  /Exception/
    InvalidParameter.php
```

And InvalidParameter Class would look something like Exception_InvalidParameter extends Exception. It is quite similar to what you have suggested in option 1.
I generally love to have all my custom library classes in to `/library/custom`

Answer (score -3):

The purpose of creating specific exception classes is to associate it with some specific functionality (database , session etc) . If your functionality can be fully described in one class for example

```
Class AdminController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

public function loginAction()
{
  throw new LoginException('Failed login');
}
}

Class LoginException extends Exception {
}
```

Note both classes are in same file AdminController.php  . This approach is faster since no autoloading is needed to load LoginException since its in same file.

Comment: This makes the `LoginException` class only usable (id. _throwable_ and _catchable_) where `AdminController` is used (id. loaded).